# History.js PushState in html 4 browser (IE) changes the url incorrectly

Tags: url, history.js, html4

Im usnig History.js to push a url but in IE it appends the page name.

if my original url is :
http://www.mydomain.com/Home.aspx

and then I execute the following:

var url = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/Home.aspx?id=2&pl=4';
History.pushState(null, null, url)

In Chrome my url becomes : http://www.mydomain.com/Home.aspx?id=2&pl=4

In IE 8 my url becomes: http://www.mydomain.com/Home.aspx#Home.aspx?id=2&pl=4

If I paste the IE 8 url in chrom my code fails...

Firstly, what should the correct html 4 url look like and secondly, how do I fix it?

Comment: Your problem is that everything after the # is NOT sent to the server. So mydomain.com/Home.aspx will never get the id and pl that are after the hash.

Comment: What you get is intended, I am using in our client site and it behaves the same way you have given and it works good.  The URL with Hash will also work correctly in Chrome browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are not pushing a state properly, try reformatting the url you push e.g. `History.pushState({data: 'home'}, null, '/Home/').`

Or maybe you thought that pushing a state also sends a request to server like you did there with a query? It does not buddy.

Therefore, dont expect anything to work by pasting the state u pushed into other browsers. First, because other browsers have no history about your site and secondly you need to catch the statechange event with History.

e.g.

```
History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange',
       function() {
         if (History.getState().data.page === 'home') {
           //do what u would like with current state
         }
     );
```

Comment: The statechange event is not the issue. That all works. If I push '/Home/' and then bookmark that page and then reload the page it wouldn't work as asp.net is expecting '.aspx' at the end of home... Im running this on a Sharepoint site.